# Using regex in hg revset

Tags: regex, mercurial

All of the documents I have read say that I can use regex in specifying the revset I am trying to use the tag() predicate, with a regex, e.g. `tag('v334.\*')` to list all versions tagged with `v3340` through `v3349`.

Leaving out the syntax errors I encountered, using the proper regex syntax as far as I can tell from pages like https://www.mercurial-scm.org/repo/hg/help/revsets (see the "PATTERNS" section) the best chance seemed to be:

```
tag(r're:v334.\*')
```

This at least parsed, but the result said that `tag 're:v334.\*' does not exist`. I know those tags exist, what am I doing wrong?

**UPDATE 1**

First ... your first response shows `re:v334` which is not a regex. It is my understanding that the `glob:` prefix specifies a simple regex, and the `re:` prefix uses the Python regex, so that should be `re:v334.*` ... yes?

Then it just doesn't work. here are both forms:

```
$ hg log -r 'tag(r"re:v334.*")'
abort: tag 're:v334.*' does not exist

$ hg log -r 'tag(r"re:v334")'
abort: tag 're:v334' does not exist
```

Oh, and using `hg tags | grep v334` does show that these tags exist.

Comment: Hello, I updated your question putting there your comments to my answer, and my answer following your comments. For the future, please follow these suggestions:

1. Do not ask questions in the comments. Instead, update your question and leave a comment to the answer just mentioning that you updated your question.

2. Do NOT use HTML formatting. Learn the very simple Markdown syntax that is supported by StackOverflow.

thanks :-)

Answer (score 1):

You were very close :-)

To list all the revisions tagged with a string beginning with `v334`:

```
hg log -r 'tag(r"re:v334")'
```

To list all the revisions tagged with `v334` followed only by one digit (so `v3347` will match but not, say, `v33478`):

```
hg log -r 'tag(r"re:v334\d$")'
```

Some additional notes:

- The `r` before the regex is not always needed but it never hurts, it is the Python way to specify a raw string.
- The `$` is to specify end of string in the regex, otherwise it would be greedy as in the first example.

**UPDATE 1**

Well, a regex doesn't need to contain special characters to be a regex :-) If you look at the [Python documentation for regex](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html), you will see that there are two functions, `match()` and `search()`. Mercurial behaves like `search()`.

To give my answer above I created a repo from scratch with some tags, so it does work for me:

```
$ hg log -r 'tag(r"re:v334\d$")'
changeset:   1:d0b5e02bb7d9
tag:         v3340

changeset:   2:566e36f5510c
tag:         v3344
```

I noticed another difference: if I search for a non-existing tag, I get an empty output, not the `abort` you get. Last suggestion I can make is to use a recent mercurial. `hg --version` tells 4.1.1 for me.

Comment: First ... your first response shows "re:v334" which is not a regex.  It is my understanding that the glob: prefix specifies a simple regex, and the re: prefix uses the python regex, so that should be "re:v334.*" ... yes? <br><br> then it just doesn't work.  here are both forms:<br>$ hg log -r 'tag(r"re:v334.*")'
<br>abort: tag 're:v334.*' does not exist
<br>$ hg log -r 'tag(r"re:v334")'
<br>abort: tag 're:v334' does not exist

Comment: oh #$@!!   The html markup you can use in the main post can't be used in comments??  I hope you can read that ...

Comment: Oh, and using "hg tags | grep v334" does show that these tags exist.

Comment: Are the valid regex expressions different for matcn() and search()?  (I can check that, consider it a rhetorical question)    Blast I can not insert a <CR> into a comment!  Ok, my version is 2.0.2.  Seriously out of date.  However, this is a company box so I do not know if I can update ...  Thanks for your help.  If I can update and still have problems I will add another comment later.

Answer (score 1):

I believe

```
hg log -r 'tag("re:v334\d")'
```

should be enough.

Comment: ...And what is the difference compared to my answer?

Comment: @marco.m simplicity